# How to instantiate a viewcontroller with an embedded navigation controller programmatically swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I'm trying to instantiate a viewcontroller that has a navigation controller embedded in it from the AppDelegate. Here's what my code looks like:

```
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      let dm = DefaultsManager.sharedManager
    if  dm.rememberMe == true {
      let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VolunteerVC")

      self.window!.rootViewController = vc
      self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

the right viewcontroller is instantiated but the navigation controller that was embedded in it is now missing. Any idea how to instantiate it with the nav controller still connected?

Comment: Difficult to understand whats going on without more information. Like what you're storyboard looks like etc. I'm pretty sure you need to create a window as well? Something like self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) before you set the rootViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, give the nav controller a name under storyboard ID in the storyboard and for the line:

```
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VolunteerVC")
```

replace the name of the viewcontroller with the name you gave the navigation controller.